# Getting heap dump after successful process

Tags: java, eclipse, heap-dump

I am using eclipse, i want to get heap dump after  my program finishes its process successfully. My program does not get heap space error or something but still i want to look at heap dump with eclipse memory analyzer. Actually what i want is a heap dump that generated automatically when program finishes succesfully like                                                           `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` parameter which generates the heap dump when getting out of memory error automatically.

Any advice would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a heap dump with `jmap` which is inlcuded in the JDK.

A heap dump can be generated  by the command line:

```
jmap -dump : live, format = b , file = < filename> < PID>
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html for further details.